# Rails: Proper Sign In structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a "Sign-In" function - :controller => "sessions" , :action => "new"

I've also edited :controller => "application" so that if I'm anywhere on the website, and I'm not logged in - I'm redirected to the root path:

```
before_filter :login_required
protected
  def login_required
    redirect_to "/" if not session[:user]
end
```

But the problem is that now I can not get to the sign in page.

It used to be localhost:3000/sessions/new

I thought that changing root path would help, so I added this to the routes.rb:

```
match '/', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
```

And after that localhost:3000 started giving the error "Wrong Forwarding" in browser.

I also don't want to have "/sessions/new/" as my default location.

Is there a way, when I go to "/" - to see the content of "/sessions/new/" and still keep my protection code in application controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using the skip_filter method as described above, consider using the Devise gem for user authentication, rather than rolling your own, unless you have a really good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
skip_filter :login_required, :only => [:new]
```

in your SessionController to skip the filter for the :new action. Also, you can match '/' by writing :

```
 root :to => 'sessions#new'
```